# PowerBI Report Cloning

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am having issue (getting 401) when try to clone the PowerBi reprot. For getting the access token i am using the folowing the methord

```
private async Task<PowerBiTokenModel> GetPowerBITokenAsync(string reportId = "")
        {
            var host = Request.Host.Value;
            var path = Request.Path.Value;
            string report_guid = "";

            bool isValidReportIdExtracted = false;
            var TokenModel = new PowerBiTokenModel();
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                //PARAMS of the call
                var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "username", _powerBiTokenSettings.username},
                    { "password",_powerBiTokenSettings.password },
                    { "client_id",_powerBiTokenSettings.client_id },
                    { "client_secret", _powerBiTokenSettings.client_secret },
                    { "resource", _powerBiTokenSettings.resource },
                    { "grant_type", _powerBiTokenSettings.grant_type },
                    { "scope" , "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default openid profile offline_access"}

                };
                //Encoded for url 
                var encodedContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);
                try
                {
                    string url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token"
                    //Post http call
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(_powerBiTokenSettings.url, encodedContent);
                    //failure case error
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    //convert response to string
                    string responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                    var jwt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PowerBiTokenModel>(responseBody);

                    return jwt;
                }
                catch (HttpRequestException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");
                    Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ", e.Message);
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }
```

and for cloning the report i am using the following method

private async Task CloneReport(string accessToken, string targetWorkspaceId, JObject reportDetails , string reportId , string sourceWorkspaceid)
{
var powerBiToken = await GetPowerBITokenAsync();

```
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", powerBiToken.access_token);
            
            string url = $"https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/reports/84aad0fa-9561-4839-bd48-dd588a39008a/Clone";
            // Modify the report details as needed (e.g., changing the report name)
            
            string targetModel = null;
            string reportName = reportDetails["name"].ToString();
            var requestBody = new
            {
                name = reportName,
                targetWorkspaceId = targetWorkspaceId
            };
            var serializedBody = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestBody);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(serializedBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

            string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to clone report: " + responseContent);
            }

            JObject clonedReport = JObject.Parse(responseContent);
            string clonedReportId = clonedReport["id"].ToString();

            return clonedReportId;
        }

    }
```

I am making a new Workspace and trying to clone the report from my main workspace to the new one.
my access token is working fine while creating the new workspace or getting the reports etc.

Comment: You can try using: [Reports - Clone Report In Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/clone-report-in-group#code-try-0), if it also throws 401 error then you don't have the required permissions.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/developer/embedded/troubleshoot-rest-api#api-call-returns-401